# jQuery duplicate and drag an image

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to create a small application where a user can drag an image an move it around.

I am using jQuery UI. I am able to create a clone but the drag stuff is not working. Also, when the clone is created it adds next to the "this" image. I want the clone and the original image to be on top of each other. So that the mousedown event creates a new image and makes it drag able, hence getting a clone effect.

A demo is at http://www.kalomaya.com/dragable/index.html

```
.draggable {
float:left;
margin-right:10px;
margin-bottom:10px;
position:relative;
}

<div class="draggable"><img src="images/imageA.png" /></div>
<div class="draggable"><img src="images/imageB.png" /></div>

<script type="application/javascript">
$(function(){
    $(".draggable").mousedown(function()
    {
        $(this).children().clone().appendTo(this);
        $(this).children().draggable();
        });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should probably be using jQueryUI's draggable functionality to do the cloning:

```
$( ".draggable" ).draggable({ helper: "clone" });
```

Update:  Since the above doesn't really answer your entire question, I created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nZhK8/1/) of what I *think* you're trying to do.

```
$('.draggable').draggable({helper: "clone"});
$('.draggable').bind('dragstop', function(event, ui) {
    $(this).after($(ui.helper).clone().draggable());
});
```

Comment: Just a quick question, when the element get's cloned, all it's 'droppable' elements don't react to it. Any idea how to rebind them to it?