# JS - I want to replicate/clone an image at initial place when it's moved from starting point

Tags: javascript, html

I have 3 draggable images. My goal is to create the same draggable image (1 or 2 or 3) on its initial place when moved. In the end I would like to have multiple images 1 and 2 and 3 on the page (number of images depends on the user interaction), all draggable.

HTML:

```
<div class="images">
    <img src="1.jpg" id="1">
    <img src="2.jpg" id="2">
    <img src="3.jpg" id="3">
</div>
```

JS:

```
$( function() {$( "#1" ).draggable();} );

$( function() {$( "#2" ).draggable();} );

$( function() {$( "#3" ).draggable();} );
```

I need help. Please advise.

Comment: You mean that when drag, the code will create another image and "keep" it in place, so the users could drag as many time they way?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be using jQueryUI's draggable functionality to do the cloning:
Here, you can apply this for your image also:

**http://jsfiddle.net/nZhK8/1/**

```
$('.draggable').draggable({helper: "clone"});
$('.draggable').bind('dragstop', function(event, ui) {
    $(this).after($(ui.helper).clone().draggable());
});
```

Original answer: [jQuery duplicate and drag an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6673675/jquery-duplicate-and-drag-an-image)